# What reading is recommended for an experienced Java/SQL Developer moving to Apache/Tomcat, Postgres, Hibernate

Tags: java, web-development, hibernate, postgres, tomcat

I am taking over management and development of a website developed in Java using Hibernate and Postgres, running on Apache/Tomcat.  I am an experienced Java developer, and have experience in Ruby on Rails, and am expert in Oracle SQL.  What is the best documentation for me to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hibernate, I can recommend [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/). I found it very useful and thorough - it may be that others feel it's too dense, but if you are an SQL expert already, I don't think you will have any problem with it.

Comment: Thanks.  It was last updated in 2006.  Is it still current?

Comment: @kevin, we haven't found any major issues with it being out of date yet. So I am confident it is good for learning the fundamental concepts and best practices, and when in doubt, you can consult the [online documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/docs).

Comment: Great.  I appreciate thoroughness.

Comment: I'm some weeks into development now, and JPwH has been very helpful.  It is not quite current for Hibernate 3.6.

Comment: @kevin, glad to hear, and good to know :-) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: We decided to do future development with Grails.  I'm finding the GORM view of hibernate to be quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

For Tomcat, the [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/index.html) is a good start.   [Tomcat: The Definitive Guide, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101066) is also worth a look.

Comment: Why? What makes them good? What is your experience with them? Please expand your answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Hibernate : [Hibernate made easy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615201954).
2. Tomcat : [Tomcat: The Definitive Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101066)

Comment: Why?  What makes them good?  What is your experience with them?  Please expand your answer.